# SQL Server - conditional / filtered foreign key. Another way

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

Often we want to reference from `Table2` only to rows in `Table1` that satisfy some predicate. Like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Table1 (
    Id       int NOT NULL,
    IsActive bit NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_Table1 PRIMARY KEY ( Id )
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Table2 (
    Id       int NOT NULL,
    Table1Id int NOT NULL
);

/* Using WHERE is unsupported: */
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table2 
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Table2_to_Table1
        FOREIGN KEY ( Table1Id ) REFERENCES Table1 ( Id ) WHERE IsActive = 1;
```

But this code does not work. Usually in this case there is recommendation to add column `IsActive` in `Table2` (always equal to `1`) and add that FK:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table2
    ADD IsActive AS (CONVERT(bit,1)) PERSISTED NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE dbo.Table1
    ADD CONSTRAINT UK_Id_IsActive
        UNIQUE ( Id, IsActive );

ALTER TABLE dbo.Table2
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Table2_to_Table1
        FOREIGN KEY ( Table1Id, IsActive ) REFERENCES Table1 ( Id, IsActive );
```

Example in this question: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/188379/filtered-foreign-keys

But if we have 10 rows in `Table1` and 1 billion rows in `Table2` we should store many redundant data.

Can we solve this problem without this overhead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
create table dbo.Table1 (
    Id int not null primary key clustered,
    IsActive bit not null,
    ActiveIdForForeignKey as iif(IsActive = 1, Id, -Id) persisted not null,
    constraint UQ_ActiveIdForForeignKey unique (ActiveIdForForeignKey)
);
go
create table dbo.Table2 (Id int not null, Table1Id int not null);
go
alter table dbo.Table2 add constraint FK_Table2_Table1 foreign key (Table1Id) references Table1(Id);
alter table dbo.Table2 add constraint FK_Table2_Table1_Active foreign key (Table1Id) references Table1(ActiveIdForForeignKey);
go
insert into dbo.Table1(Id, IsActive) values (1, 0);
insert into dbo.Table1(Id, IsActive) values (2, 1);
insert into dbo.Table1(Id, IsActive) values (3, 0);
go
insert into dbo.Table2(Id, Table1Id) values (1, 2); -- success
insert into dbo.Table2(Id, Table1Id) values (2, 1); -- fail
go
```

This is working without data store overhead for Table2.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that this has a side-effect of not allowing any records in `Table1` that are referenced in `Table2` to have their `IsActive` value changed.

Comment: @Diado Yes, but common solution have same behavior. And this is a feature, not a bug :)

Comment: This solution does not work "without storage overhead", because the ActiveIdForForeignKey column is still being persisted (i.e. stored). Worse, because the computed column has an actual calculation, it has to be recomputed if values in any of the referenced columns change (which can result in a performance hit if an operation affects multiple records). At least with the "IsActive as cast(1 as bit) persisted" approach, there is no calculation. Finally, the "IsActive = 1" approach is more efficient storage-wise, because it uses 1 byte versus 4 to store the data.

Comment: @Eric of course I say this only about Table2. Table1 has, for example, 20 rows, but Table2 can store millions and more. I have edited my answer to specify that.

Comment: @Diado What if you use `ON UPDATE CASCADE`?